# Getting 404 error calling Sitecore ItemWebApi through Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I was trying to follow the tutorial in this video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfnTJsUKxiY 
and also this blog: 
https://cmsview.wordpress.com/tag/sitecore-speak-for-beginners/

They example of these tutorials both initiate ajax call to the url `/api/sitecore/{controller}/{action}`. Is it a default Sitecore behaviour that it redirects to that controller action or do I need to config the route by myself? I can't get this url working as the tutorials have shown. Everytime it is 404 error. I am using Sitecore 8.

Thanks.

edited:
below is the code in my controller class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SwireCitygate.Web.Controllers
{
    public class MembersBehaviourReportsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Default
        public ActionResult GetText()
        {
            string text = "Hello World";

            return Json(text, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

It is inheriting System.Web.Mvc.Controller

and the JS file:

```
define(["sitecore"], function (Sitecore) {
    var model = Sitecore.Definitions.Models.ControlModel.extend({
        initialize: function (options) {
            this._super();

            this.set("output", null);
            this.GetText(this);
        },
        GetText: function (app) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/api/sitecore/MembersBehaviourReports/GetText",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    app.set("output", data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("There was an error in GetText() function!");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    var view = Sitecore.Definitions.Views.ControlView.extend({
        initialize: function (options) {
            this._super();

            this.set("output", null);
        }
    });

    Sitecore.Factories.createComponent("MembersBehaviourReportsDataSource", model, view, ".sc-MembersBehaviourReportsDataSource");
});
```

Comment: What is the url you use? You should not use word controller in they url, e.g. if you have `MyCustomController` class, you should use `/api/sitecore/mycustom/someaction`.

Comment: i use exactly `/api/sitecore/mycustom/someaction`, but it just doesn't work

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: code snippet added to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afterall, the problem is caused by Sitecore configuration. The ItemWebAPI is not enabled.

```
<site name="website">
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.mode">Off</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.access">ReadOnly</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess">false</patch:attribute>
</site>
```

I set the itemwebapi.mode to StandardSecurity and itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess to true, then it worked magically.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, I would say that you should ensure your Controller is inheriting from the MVC Controller `System.Web.Controller` and not the WebApi controller `System.Web.Http.ApiController`.

If you're using a WebApi Controller, you'll need to setup a custom route instead of using /api/sitecore/...